# How to set variables in array (within a foreach loop) to be accessed in a different class?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, foreach

Basically, I have an array of data, which I have split into pairs. In this case string firstTicker and string secondTicker. I would like to run a job in a seperate class that uses the instances of the 'firstTicker' and 'secondTicker'. Is there a way to declare these strings so that they may be accessed outside?

```
static void Main(string[] args)     
{
    string _myPairList = GlobalVar.GlobalString; 

    //For reference: _myPairList="Joe,Brown;Bill,Lowry;Sara,Moncton"

    string[] pairListArray = _myPairList.Split(';');       

    foreach (string tickerPair in pairListArray)           
    {
        string[] tickerPairDualArray = tickerPair.Split(',');

        // Command: I'd like to run a job in a seperate class with the two seperated 
        // tickers as variables for each set. (i.e. 'Joe' and 'Brown', 
        // 'Bill' and 'Lowry', 'Sara' and 'Moncton' are all run in the 
        // same program with the respective variables

        string firstTicker = tickerPairDualArray[0];
        string secondTicker = tickerPairDualArray[1];
    }        

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Can't you pass the strings into the method of the other class?

Comment: There should be no problem doing that.  Please provide your class code and how you're trying to access them.

Comment: Are you trying to pass your data into another class, or have your other class essentially poll this one? In the former, you should be able to simply pass the values forward. In the latter, you can declare your tickerFields as properties, possibly add an event which your polling class subscribes to, and invoke it each time the loop is iterated through.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - in your other class that you've written, have your constructor or methods take string parameters. When you want to process those strings in your Main method, simply call `YourMethod(firstTicker, secondTicker);`, or if you want to add them to a class's data, `MyClass obj = new MyClass(firstTicker, secondTicker);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply wanting to call into another class which has the functionality you want, then Jeremy's answer should be good.

If you're wanting to be able to attach arbitrary code from another class to the loop, then an event is an effective way to go. Add something like the following to your code:

```
public static event EventHandler<TickerEventArgs> TickerLoopIterated;

private static void InvokeTickerLoopEvent(string firstTicker, string secondTicker)
{
    if (null != TickerLoopIterated)
    { 
        var args = new TickerEventArgs() { FirstTicker = firstTicker, SecondTicker = secondTicker };
        TickerLoopIterated(this, args); 
    }
}

public class TickerEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string FirstTicker { get; set; }
    public string SecondTicker { get; set; }
}
```

And invoke it inside your loop when your values are ready

```
InvokeTickerLoopEvent(firstTicker, secondTicker);
```

Then in your other class, subscribe to the event somewhere in the code, probably in the initialization phase, like so:

```
NameOfTheClassWithYourTickerLoop.TickerLoopIterated += SomeCodeIWantToExecute;
```

And elsewhere in that class:

```
private void SomeCodeIWantToExecute(object sender, TickerEventArgs args)
{
    //Your code here
}
```

Note that the event is static because your example is in the public static void main method. Throw that bad boy into an object class and you can use an instance event.